# How do i convert a str to a float?

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, dataframe, floating-point

Input:

```
df.groupby('Age Group').size()
```

Output:

```
  18 thru 24      352
  25 thru 34      358
  35 thru 44      341
  45 thru 54      336
  55 and Older    269
  Under 18        103
  dtype: int64
```

input:

```
age = df.loc[df['Age Group']== '18 thru 24'].count()[0]
labels = ['18 thru 24']
plt.pie(['18 thru 24'], labels = labels)
plt.show()
```

output:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '18 thru 24'
```

Comment: @Rodrez says : Can you provide more details on what your code should do, and your expected results? (*from deleted answer*)

Comment: the objective is to create a pie chart that gives each value as a float or percentage.

Comment: See https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_features.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pie-and-polar-charts-pie-features-py for an example on how to make a pie chart.  The first argument needs to be an _array-like_ variable, and `labels` needs to be _A sequence of strings providing the labels for each wedge_. I'm not really familiar with pandas, so I don't know how to get the data and labels from your dataframe. Maybe `df.groupby('Age Group').columns` and `df.groupby('Age Group').values`.